# How to select the laptop correct driver

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, laptop, drivers

How can I choose the correct laptop Wifi driver for my **HP 630 notebook** laptop?

I go to the relevant HP site and choose my operating system. It gives me the list of drivers but how would I know what is the correct vendor of my wireless network adapter.

[image]

[Here is the link to that web page](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareIndex.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&prodNameId=5086783&prodTypeId=321957&prodSeriesId=5086782&swLang=13&taskId=135&swEnvOID=4053#11360)

Answer (score 0):

If you're simply looking to update the driver then go to device manager and find network adapter under which it should list the driver with the name of the manufacturer and you can select the option accordingly on the HP website.

A pre-built pc/laptop may normally have parts from different manufacturers and assuming that it is not the former case where you want to update the driver then we've got to look for the specification on either the paper which came with the notebook or refer to the website. I see there are 5 different products found with the keyword HP 630 Notebook Pc - I would recommend that you either look up your product using the serial number and product number or else allow HP to automatically detect your information by clicking on detect my product on the drivers and downloads page. Hope it helps !!

Answer (score 0):

You may use the tool EasyDriverPro for search appropriate driver for laptop and install it